# Deleting a key from a ThreadLocalStorage in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I can create a Thread Local variable in Ruby by following:

```
Thread.current[:ab] = 123
```

I have not found any documentation on how to remove a particular key from Thread Local storage. I just want to remove a particular key and retain all others.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the answer.
Simply saying following should suffice:

```
Thread.current[:ab] = nil
```

Answer (score 3):

`#[]` and `#[]=` are not [thread](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html)-local but [fiber](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fiber.html)-local.

```
=> Thread.current[:ab] = 'foo'
=> "foo"
=> Thread.current.thread_variables
=> []
=> Thread.current.thread_variable_set(:ab, 'foo')
=> "foo"
=> Thread.current.thread_variables
=> [:ab]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you also explain when to use Thread-Local vs Fiber-Local ?

Comment: It's explained here https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Thread.html#class-Thread-label-Fiber-local+vs.+Thread-local
`Thread.current[:something]` will not be carried into fiber but `Thread.current.thread_variables` will